# How do I make the background transparent?

Tags: css

I am fairly new to CSS, I need to do this for course work. I came across this problem, I am not sure how to make the background the only transparent bit, and not the rest of the divs. Please check out this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/LfWBn/

```
html,body {
background-color:orange;
background-size:auto;
opacity:0.6;
z-index:1;
}
```

I understand that the bar is all out of place, but when it is viewed in safari it goes back to normal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add rgba to your color background

```
html,body {
  background:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
 }
```

Comment: You should remove the opacity: 0.6 you don't needed

Comment: `Background` with a capital `B` ?

Comment: @srekoble to me looks like a copy-paste race (see Devcon's answer) :)

Comment: Thank you @srekoble and Devcon 2, both answers helped me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Background-color:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
```

Comment: `Background` with a capital `B`? is this a copy-paste race?